# Why does json_decode gets syntax error in 1 pc and works fine in another

Tags: php, json

So here is the situation.

Our client side code, side_nav.php (in local apache server)

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://ourserver.com/get_side_nav.php');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $output = curl_exec ($ch); // Executr
  curl_close ($ch); // Close cURL handl




// i added this to remove invalid chars

for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i) {
    $output = str_replace(chr($i), "", $output);
}
$output = str_replace(chr(127), "", $output);

if (0 === strpos(bin2hex($output), 'efbbbf')) {
   $output = substr($output, 3);
}

$data = json_decode($output);

// outputs the json object.
echo var_dump($data);

if(json_last_error() != 0){
  echo 'ERROR JSON CODE ' . json_last_error();
}
```

and our get_side_nav.php (server) returns this json when called.

```
{"navs":[{"href":"index.php","class":"fa fa-dashboard","name":"Dashboard"},{"href":"inventory.php","class":"fa fa-dropbox","name":"Inventory"},{"href":"gr_list.php","class":"fa fa-money","name":"Goods Received"},{"href":"new_sales.php","class":"fa fa-money","name":"Sales"},{"href":"credit_sales.php","class":"fa fa-paste","name":"Credit Sales"}]}
```

And the problem is, for some reason, i couldn't get pc 2 to decode JSON successfully, it returns JSON error 4 which is JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX. Both PCS are running the exact same version of wampserver. The other PC though, decodes the JSON it gets from our server and displays the object successfully.

Comment: Did you check if both pc's generate the same json?

Comment: Yes both pcs get the same json through browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do some comparison of the raw `$data` *before* you do the `json_decode()`, to see if they already differ at that point.  If something like a proxy server blocks or alters the curl path from one PC but not the other, then perhaps the "bad PC" is getting raw `$data` that is an HTML blocking page.

Comment: Thank you. Since when the 2 pcs were requesting data from the same server and it worked for one , i didn't care to check this one. When i checked the output of the curl request it turned out it was getting a forbidden page. I've now fixed it. :)